# How do I determine the dimension arguments for glTexImage3D?

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm working on a graphics project involving using a 3D texture to do some volume rendering on data stored in the form of a rectilinear grid, and I was a little confused on the width, height, and depth arguments for glTexImage3D.  For a 1D texture, I know that you can use something like this:

glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

where the width is the 256 possible values for each color stream.  Here, I'm still using colors in the form of unsigned bytes (and the main purpose of the texture here is still to interpolate the colors of the points in the grid, along with the transparencies), so it makes sense to me that one of the arguments would still be 256.  It's a 64 X 64 X 64 grid, so it makes sense that one of the arguments (maybe the depth?) would be 64, but I'm not sure about the third, or even if I'm on the right track there.  Could anyone enlighten me on the proper use of those three parameters?  I looked at both of these discussions, but still came away confused:

[regarding glTexImage3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377700/regarding-glteximage3d)

[OPENGL how to use glTexImage3D function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553671/opengl-how-to-use-glteximage3d-function)

Comment: How are you planning on to render the date from the 3D texture. OpenGL 3D textures are not "magical" volume rasterizers. When drawing regular OpenGL primitives you can cut "slices" out of the volume, but it will not be a volumetric rendering automatically. For that to happen you must implement some kind of volume raycaster or similar.

Comment: *"where the width is the 256 possible values for each color stream"* –– total misunderstanding of what it does. The `width` (and height and depth) parameter tells, how many pixels to allocate for the texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstood the 1D case. In your example, 256 is the size of the 1D texture, i.e. the number of texels.

The number of possible values for each color component is given by the internal format, which is the 3rd argument. `GL_RGB` actually leaves it up to the implementation what the color depth should be. It is supported for backwards compatibility with old code. It gets clearer if you specify a sized format like `GL_RGB8` for the internal format, which requests 8 bits per color component, which corresponds to 256 possible values each for R, G, and B.

For the 3D case, if you want a 64 x 64 x 64 grid, you simply specify 64 for the size in each of the 3 dimensions (width, height, and depth). Say for this size, using RGBA and a color depth of 8 bits, the call is:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 64, 64, 64, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Comment: I see.  I guess it was just a happy coincidence that using that glTexImage1D call worked before, then.  Setting each parameter to 64 was actually one of the first things I tried, but it just gave me a completely black screen.  So far the one that's given me the best image are using these: glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB, 16, 256, 64, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, RGBColors);  I should note that it is a regular grid (i.e., that it uses regular spacing), but it is not a unit grid. I'm trying to format my glTexCoord3f's as one, though.

Comment: That would be correct for a 16x256x64 grid of RGB values. You said you had transparencies, so I figured you probably had RGBA data. It's actually much more common for volume rendering to use single-channel data that just contains intensities, and mapping it to colors with a transfer function. But it really depends on the format of your input data. In the end, it should look something like this: http://retokoradi.com/volume-rendering/ :)

Comment: You were right to assume that about the transparencies - I'm just trying to get the colors working properly before I add in the transparencies. I am actually using a transfer function as well - the *data parameter comes from me applying it to the field values for the points on the grid.

Comment: Ah, I didn't expect changing those parameters to affect the camera settings I'd need.  I think that was actually one of my main mistakes.  Thanks, Reto.